# How to test internet connectivity of network to which esp32 is connected?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I want to know if the network to which esp connected has internet connectivity or not. How can I send a ping request using esp32?

Comment: We expect you to have done some basic research before asking a question (and explain why what you've found doesn't work)

Comment: a quick google search of `esp32 ping` provides plenty of results. :-)

Comment: use the http client to fetch a small file/page from the internet, one that you expect will always be up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test internet connectivity the best way is to request http://google.com. If your device is connected to internet, you would get 301 as response code.

Answer (score 0):

You can ping some address and see if it is reachable. You can use [this library](https://github.com/marian-craciunescu/ESP32Ping) for the same.

Comment: Are you sure? That just means you are connected to an access point, not that you have internet access.

Comment: Ohh yeah, foolish me. I misunderstood something in the question. I have edited the answer.

Comment: This is now basically a link only answer which will become useless if the link breaks.